# embed video in html: using object tag

Tags: html, flash, video, media-player

I have been trying to make my own customized video player for a website, but i don't really get how you are supposed to do. I've watched video's on youtube how you make your own flash player, but they embed the video in it in flash and there must be another way, like creating the player design, then having a html tag telling the video path and stuff. I've seen other video sites like movpod (i use it to watch stuff like the simpsons :p). They have an object tag in their site with the .swf player (design), but if i go to that file, it only shows up the design of the player, not the actual video. They are then using param tags to define the path to the video in the page. My question is, how do you make the player design, without importing a video in like flash cs5 or something, using said said object tag to the design, and params to define what actual video you want to watch.

Answer (score 1):

The params passed are usually FlashVars. It's basically a Parameter in the object or embed tag defining some variables you can access in Flash, i.e. the adress of the video to play. See  http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashVars/index.html example 1

In Flash then you read the address to the video and load it, i.e. using a FLVPlayback object.

Comment: I still don't get how you _style_ the video, like pause and play buttons.